# Fetching data from api and passing it to state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a random quote generator, and, for some reason, I'm not able to pass the information from the API to my state and I can't make the QuoteComponent receive the data as props. Apparently I'm doing everything correctly, but I keep getting 'undefined' when i 'console.log' my state to see if the information is there. here's the code(two simple components, the App and the QuoteComponent):

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import QuoteComponent from "./QuoteComponent";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      qouteData: []
    };
    this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
  }

  fetchData() {
    fetch("https://api.quotable.io/quotes")
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          quoteData: data
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.quoteData);

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <QuoteComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

QuoteComponent

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function QuoteComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="flex">
          <div id="quote">
            <h2>{props.quote}</h2>
          </div>
          <div id="quote-a">
            <h4>{props.author}</h4>
          </div>
          <div id="button">
            <button onClick={props.handleClick}>New Quote</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default QuoteComponent;
```

Comment: Could you check network tab under chrome dev tools? Is there request to `https://api.quotable.io/quotes` or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You havn't passed `props` to the component :

```
<QuoteComponent />
```

It should look like this :

```
<QuoteComponent {...this.state.qouteData} handleClick={your_click_handleer}/>

//OR

<QuoteComponent 
    quote={this.state.qouteData.quote} 
    author={this.state.qouteData.author}
    handleClick={your_click_handleer}/>
```

---

Run the below code snippet, hope that will clear your doubts :

```js
function QuoteComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="flex">
          <div id="quote">
            <h2>{props.content}</h2>
          </div>
          <div id="quote-a">
            <h4>{props.author}</h4>
          </div>
          <div id="button">
            <button onClick={props.handleClick}>Get Random Quote</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      qouteData: []
    };
    this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
  }

  fetchData() {
    fetch("https://api.quotable.io/random")
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          quoteData: data
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        
        <QuoteComponent {...this.state.quoteData} handleClick={this.fetchData}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```